# Want to rent mother-in-law suite to short-term, vacation renters, what type of business should I establish to protect me?

Tags: rental-property, insurance

I am trying to figure out **what type of business** *(not what type of insurance)* I should establish to protect us from people who might do stupid things while on our property. *For example*, if someone injures himself while misusing the instant hot water, how do we ensure we're protected against litigious, accident prone, stupid people? Is an LLC enough? Thank you for any help!!
I will not have ANY employees. It's just me and my husband and I will be the "inn-keeper". I realize I need to get insurance as well, but I'm trying to understand if an LLC is the best way to go for establishing ourselves as a business.

Comment: What country (and if in the US, which state)?

Comment: USA, Washington state, Kitsap County

Answer (score 1):

You generally wouldn't need a business entity to protect you: you would buy landlord's insurance so that if someone sued you the insurance company would step in and either settle or defend the claim on your behalf.

Comment: Unfortunately, both landlord insurance and homeowners insurance exempts accidents related to a short-term rental business you do in your home. But thank you for your time and input!! It is much appreciated.

Comment: There are policies that cover short term holiday landlords - keep looking

Comment: It seems not in the United States... hopefully someone will come along who has heard of a company that does this type of insurance. I'll keep looking. Thanks again! :-)